# Multiple print on game in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a console hangman game. If I get a question wrong it prints a man getting hanged by his head and then if I missed again it prints the new image as well as the previous one (see the output below). How can I show only one text image?

Here is my code:

```
import random
import urllib


animals = urllib.urlopen('http://davidbau.com/data/animals').read().split()
#animals = ('dog','cat','sheep','mouse','frog','worm','bird','lion','dear')
while True:

    print 'time to play hangman'
    print 'hint: the word is an animail'
    secret = random.choice(animals)
    guesses = 'aeiou'
    turns = 5

    while turns > 0:
        missed = 0
        for letter in secret:
            if letter in guesses:
                print letter,
            else:
                print '_',
                missed += 1

        print

        if missed == 0:
            print 'You win!'
            break

        guess = raw_input('guess a letter: ')
        guesses += guess

        if guess not in secret:
            turns -= 1
            print 'Nope.'
            print turns, 'more turns'
            if turns < 5: print """
-------
|   |
|   O
|
|
|
|
|
---------
"""
            if turns < 4: print """
-------
|   |
|   O
| \_|_/
|
|
|
|
---------
"""
            if turns < 3: print """
-------
|   |
|   O
| \_|_/
|   |
|
|
|
---------
"""
            if turns < 2: print """
-------
|   |
|   O
| \_|_/
|   |
|  / \
|
|
---------
"""
            if turns < 1: print """
-------
|   |
|   O
| \_|_/
|   |
|  / \
| d   b
|
---------
"""
            if turns == 0:
                print 'The answer is', secret
                break


    user = raw_input("\n\tShall we play another game? [y|n] ")
    again = "yes".startswith(user.strip().lower())
    if not again:
        raw_input ("\n\n\nPress enter to exit")
        break
```

Here is the output (notice how it prints multiple times):

```
================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
>>> time to play hangman
hint: the word is an animail
_ _ a _ _ i _ _
guess a letter: p
Nope.
4 more turns

-------
|   |
|   O
|
|
|
|
|
---------

_ _ a _ _ i _ _
guess a letter: g
Nope.
3 more turns

-------
|   |
|   O
|
|
|
|
|
---------


-------
|   |
|   O
| \_|_/
|
|
|
|
---------

_ _ a _ _ i _ _
guess a letter: l
Nope.
2 more turns

-------
|   |
|   O
|
|
|
|
|
---------


-------
|   |
|   O
| \_|_/
|
|
|
|
---------


-------
|   |
|   O
| \_|_/
|   |
|
|
|
---------

_ _ a _ _ i _ _
guess a letter: m
Nope.
1 more turns

-------
|   |
|   O
|
|
|
|
|
---------


-------
|   |
|   O
| \_|_/
|
|
|
|
---------


-------
|   |
|   O
| \_|_/
|   |
|
|
|
---------


-------
|   |
|   O
| \_|_/
|   |
|  / |
|
---------

_ _ a _ _ i _ _
guess a letter: n
Nope.
0 more turns

-------
|   |
|   O
|
|
|
|
|
---------


-------
|   |
|   O
| \_|_/
|
|
|
|
---------


-------
|   |
|   O
| \_|_/
|   |
|
|
|
---------


-------
|   |
|   O
| \_|_/
|   |
|  / |
|
---------


-------
|   |
|   O
| \_|_/
|   |
|  / | d   b
|
---------

The answer is crayfish

    Shall we play another game? [y|n]
```

Comment: You should accept the correct answer in your previous question, instead of editing your question. Nobody's gonna answer your new questions, if they wont get accepted.

Comment: they both helped an i tried clicking but i didn't know which one to click because they both helped a bunch

Comment: _"ok so i asked a question earlier about looping a hangman game and it was solved but now my problem is i'm trying to spice up my hangman game but my problem is when it run i changed how the gfx look and now they print the variables gfx above it also so if i were to say get a question wrong it would print a man getting hanged by his head and then if i missed again it would print the new image as well as the image above it."_ Please use shorter sentences; this one sentence is trying to convey approximately 4 ideas and is very hard to understand.

Comment: look at the script and then look at the output it hard to describe

Comment: it makes since since someone edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having comes from the fact that your game-state checking logic is, frankly, bad. You should be using `if/elif` clauses instead of `if/if` clauses. For example:

```
if turns < 5: print "..."
if turns < 4: print "..."
if turns < 3: print "..."
if turns < 2: print "..."
if turns < 1: print "..."
```

All of these conditions are true for `turns=0`. Instead, reverse the terms so `1` comes before `5`, then structure this with `if` then `elif` clasues so only one can be true at a time. Additionally, you could use `==` instead of `<` and that would solve the problem too.

Comment: Thank you i was a little confused as im new to python but your == solved my problem